# How to stop the buttons overflowing in material ui table row while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Buttons in the table cell are overlaying the table header while scrolling.
here is the demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/qx24l9vrz6
any help is appreciated.

Comment: `z-index:9999` on `.SimpleTable-head-2` ? ( the sticky element(s) )

Comment: But if he is using some modal, then there is a chance that the buttons have higher z-index than the modal and that will cause the buttons to be floated over the modal. So, I won't recommend using this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple solution

```
.SimpleTable-head-2 {
    //Code you already have
    z-index: 3;
}

.MuiButton-sizeSmall-31 {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work. I am having the zIndex value so that it doesn't overflow any other components

Answer (score 0):

just give that class `.SimpleTable-head-2`  `z-index: 999;` any higher number it will fix your problem

Comment: But if he is using some modal, then there is a chance that the buttons have higher `z-index` than the modal and that will cause the buttons to be floated over the modal. So, I won't recommend using this

Comment: i just wrote any higher number you can define what you want and for sure if you have a modal you can also define your `z-index` according your needs it can be 999 or 10 or any number depends on what you got on your application/website